# Position <div> over image with CSS 3D transforms like augmented reality

Tags: css, css-transforms

I am trying to position a `<div>` over a photograph of a TV on a wall, so it looks like the `<div>` is on the TV.

I am sure the solution is in using CSS 3D transforms and so `perspective`, `perspective-origin`, `transform` and `transform-origin`. However I can't work out values of these which achieve a good result because I'm using trial and error - I don't know the maths.

This is my progress:

[image: progress]

And a jsfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/2pye7nc2/

I am setting perspective on the container:

```
perspective: 500px;
perspective-origin: 210px 382px;
```

And transform on the element inside it:

```
transform: translateX(153px) translateY(253px) translateZ(0) rotateX(-12deg) rotateY(-31deg) rotateZ(-20deg);
transform-origin: 0px 150px;
```

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: [The maths behind (2D-transforms)](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/01/07/css3-matrix-transform-for-the-mathematically-challenged/) (multiplying matrices). Maybe you can inject your image behind the grid or find another tool that would allow it?

Comment: Wow; thanks so much for this. It's going to do the job perfectly for next time. My original (and only) criticism is that the matrix syntax is unreadable to humans, but other `transform` ones are modified by guesswork as well, at least by me. Take a look at my comment on the marked answer for our final attempt.

Comment: As a former chemist, I had to learn how to multiply matrices so it's now easy but yeah it's quite strange if you never manipulated any ^^ and you won't figure by yourself where is the useful pattern in all these numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I could do:

```
.tv .tv-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.75;
    width: 392px;
    height: 356px;
    transform: translateX(193px) translateY(211px) translateZ(0) rotateX(-11deg) rotateY(-40deg) rotateZ(-19.5deg);
    transform-origin: 0px 150px;
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    background-color: red;
    color: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lzf2umzf/

Will that help?

Comment: Thank you! I tweaked the values slightly and embedded a YouTube video (warning - auto plays loudly): http://jadaradix.com/tv.html

Comment: Looks great, actually! :D